# SQL 2005 Cluster - How to move MSDTC

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, cluster, msdtc

We currently have a 2 node (Win2003) SQL 2005 Cluster running 2 instances.

We need to move all drives to a new SAN but are pondering over how to move the DTC that is currently 'logging' te Quorum drive.

How can we see if the MSDTC is actually in use? The log file shows a date over 2 years old, but looking at the DTC service - its started.

Also whats the best way of moving it? Can we just hack the registry to change any reference to the current drive letter?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

At a previous job, I used to have to install new clusters all the time.  So I came up with a command file to do the install.  It should provide a way forward for you.  Just make sure you change the relevant parts (server names, IP addresses, disks).

```
cluster ClusterName group "MSDTC Group" /create
cluster ClusterName group "MSDTC Group" /setowners:server1,server2

cluster ClusterName res "MSDTC IP Address" /create /group:"MSDTC Group" /type:"IP Address"
cluster ClusterName res "MSDTC IP Address" /priv network=public
cluster ClusterName res "MSDTC IP Address" /priv Address=127.0.0.1
cluster ClusterName res "MSDTC IP Address" /priv SubnetMask=255.255.255.0

cluster ClusterName res "MSDTC Network Name" /create /type:"Network Name" /group:"MSDTC Group"
cluster ClusterName res "MSDTC Network Name" /priv Name=MSDTCClusterName
cluster ClusterName res "MSDTC Network Name" /adddep:"MSDTC IP Address"

cluster ClusterName res "Disk M:\" /move:"MSDTC Group"

cluster ClusterName res "MSDTC Resource" /CREATE /GROUP:"MSDTC Group" /TYPE:"Distributed Transaction Coordinator"
cluster ClusterName res "MSDTC Resource" /ADDDEP:"MSDTC Network Name"
cluster ClusterName res "MSDTC Resource" /ADDDEP:"Disk M:\"
cluster ClusterName res "MSDTC Resource" /ON
```

Answer (score 0):

If not in use with open transactions, you can also just delete the previous MSDTC clustered resource and create a new one instead. Once it is created with new disk dependency it will create its \MSDTC subfolder in the new disk at first startup.

Powershell sample with MSDTC and MSMQ:

```
# In MSDTC and MSMQ disks, remove the MSMQ and MSDTC folders to start fresh (after deleting the clustered MSDTC and MSMQ resources)
# Add resources with parameters and dependencies
Add-ClusterResource -name "IP Address 192.168.2.72" -Group "MSMQCluster2" -ResourceType "IP Address"
Get-ClusterResource -Name "IP Address 192.168.2.72" | Set-ClusterParameter -Multiple @{"Address"="192.168.2.72";"Network"="Cluster Network 1";"SubnetMask"="255.255.255.0";EnableNetBIOS=1}
Add-ClusterResource -name "MSMQCluster2" -Group "MSMQCluster2" -ResourceType "Network Name"
Get-ClusterResource -Name "MSMQCluster2" | Set-ClusterParameter -Multiple @{"DnsName"="MSMQCluster2";"PublishPTRRecords"=1}
Set-ClusterResourceDependency -Resource "MSMQCluster2" -Dependency "[IP Address 192.168.2.72]"
Add-ClusterResource -name "MSMQCluster2DTC" -Group "MSMQCluster2" -ResourceType "Distributed Transaction Coordinator"
Set-ClusterResourceDependency -Resource "MSMQCluster2DTC" -Dependency "([MSDTC2Disk]) and ([MSMQCluster2])"
Add-ClusterResource -name "MSMQ-MSMQCluster2" -Group "MSMQCluster2" -ResourceType "MSMQ"
Set-ClusterResourceDependency -Resource MSMQ-MSMQCluster2 -Dependency "([MSMQ2Disk]) and ([MSMQCluster2])"
Start-ClusterResource -name "IP Address 192.168.2.72"
Start-ClusterResource -name "MSMQCluster2"
Start-ClusterResource -name "MSMQCluster2DTC"
Start-ClusterResource -name "MSMQ-MSMQCluster2"
```